# RegEx that will match the last occurrence of dot in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a filename that can have multiple dots in it and could end with any extension:

```
tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.png
```

I need to use a regex to replace the last occurrence of the dot with another string like `@2x` and then the dot again (very much like a retina image filename) i.e.:

```
tro.lo.png -> tro.lo@2x.png
```

Here's what I have so far but it won't match anything...

```
str = "http://example.com/image.png";
str.replace(/.([^.]*)$/, " @2x.");
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You need a negative lookahead if you want to do it with regex but you really shouldn't

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You do not need a regex for this. [`String.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) will do.

```
var str = 'tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.zip';
var i = str.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i != -1) {
    str = str.substr(0, i) + "@2x" + str.substr(i);
}
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/7aphC/)**.

**Update:** A regex solution, just for the fun of it:

```
str = str.replace(/\.(?=[^.]*$)/, "@2x.");
```

Matches a literal dot and then asserts (`(?=)` is [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) that no other character up to the end of the string is a dot. The replacement should include the one dot that was matched, unless you want to remove it.

Comment: That returns an integer of the position where that character is, right?

Comment: How can I use that integer with .replace() ?

Comment: @JacksonGariety: You don't need to. `String.substr` will round things up.

Comment: Cool answer! Why is this better/more efficient/less code than a regex?

Comment: @JacksonGariety. It's a lot more readable, and little bit faster.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: Cool, thanks. I also added a regex solution for completeness.

Comment: Heya, quick new question for the RegExpert... How would I best remove the beginning `'url('` and closing `')'` around a url without removing them from elsewhere in the string? Thanks.

Comment: You 'd match `"url\((-url-regex-here-)\)"` and replace with `"$1"`, which would leave only the url. `-url-regex-here-` is a regular expression that matches urls; google for that, for a quick and dirty solution that mostly works you could use `[^)]+`.

Answer (score 32):

Just use [special replacement pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) `$1` in the replacement string:

```js
console.log("tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.png".replace(/\.([^.]+)$/, "@2x.$1"));
// "tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo@2x.png"
```

Comment: @Qtax: Not quite, because it won't work if the last dot is also the very last character.

Comment: @Jon, true. Almost korrect then. ;) But `/\.([^.]*)$/` does it, no need for lookarounds.

Comment: I am not sure if a filename could have a `.` as the very last character.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the expression `\.([^.]*?)`:

```
str.replace(/\.([^.]*?)$/, "@2x.$1");
```

You need to reference the `$1` subgroup to copy the portion back into the resulting string.

Comment: I think this needs another period at the end of "$1@2x" to work, right?

Comment: Was a bit hasty with that answer — fixed it to make more sense w.r.t. your original regex

Comment: I think you are missing a `.` in the replacement string. I prefer escaping `.`, but character class may be easier to read. `.replace(/(.*)\./, "$1@2x.")`. Anyway, +1 for a simple solution using the greedy property of `*` quantifier.

Answer (score 5):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/AbDyh/1/

**code**

```
var str = 'tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.zip',
    replacement = '@2x.';
str = str.replace(/.([^.]*)$/, replacement + '$1');

$('.test').html(str);

alert(str);​
```

Comment: Not quite. the output is missing a dot.

Comment: **Output should be** `tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo@2x.zip`  **You output** `tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo@2xzip`

Comment: @gdoron lol 35 second difference :) cheers **updated version here** http://jsfiddle.net/AbDyh/1/

Answer (score 3):

To match all characters from the beginning of the string until (and including) the last occurence of a character use:

```
^.*\.(?=[^.]*$)  To match the last occurrence of the "." character

^.*_(?=[^.]*$)   To match the last occurrence of the "_" character
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\.` to match a dot. The character `.` matches *any* character.

Therefore `str.replace(/\.([^\.]*)$/, ' @2x.')`.

Comment: Try your code: `"tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.zip".replace(/\.([^\.]*)$/, ' @2x.')` It doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: Cool, did not know that about regex

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do like this,

```
> "tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.zip".replace(/^(.*)\./, "$1@2x");
'tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo@2xzip'
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa `.*` matches as much as possible of anything, so it pushes the rest of the match to the end of the string

Comment: I fully understand this answer -- I am merely pointing out that this is a snippet dump which is a suboptimal way of sharing knowledge with readers who will visit this page.  Please [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply split the string and add said suffix to the second to last entry:

```
var arr = 'tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.zip'.split('.');
arr[arr.length-2] += '@2x';
var newString = arr.join('.');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'tro.lo.lo.lo.lo.lo.png'.replace(/([^\.]+).+(\.[^.]+)/, "$1.@x2$2")
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.