# Javascript regex to match from the last occurrence of pattern until a different pattern across multiple lines

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a sample of the html I am trying to match

```
<div><p>Hello World</p></div>
<hr style="margin: 10px">
<div><p>Regex is hard</p></div>


<div><p>Hello World</p></div>
<hr style="margin: 10px">
<div><p>Regex is hard</p></div>


<div><p>Block I want to Match</p></div>
<hr style="margin: 10px">
<div><p>Matching Text</p></div>
```

I want to be able to grab:

```
<hr style="margin: 10px">
<div><p>Matching Text</p></div>
```

However I cannot seem to figure out the regex I need to use. I have found examples such as this: [RegEx that will match the last occurrence of dot in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134004/regex-that-will-match-the-last-occurrence-of-dot-in-a-string). But I cannot seem to adapt that to my use case.

**EDIT:** Should have specified...the occurrence I am trying to match will always be the last occurrence.

Comment: (1) What have you tried and what did it achieve? (2) What is significantly different about the third lump of text that can be used to find it, or do you want the very last occurrence?

Comment: It will always be the very last occurrence that I am trying to match. 

After some further testing, this regex `<hr(?=[^<hr]*$)[^]*<\/div>` should work... however the negated set `[^<hr]` doesn't work in this scenario since the set searches for any character inside the set rather than the whole string. Is there any way to have a negated string rather than a negated set?

Comment: Don't process HTML with regexps. If you want to match that in order to remove it, consider instead using CSS to hide it.

Comment: @torazaburo I want to match it in order to replace it with a different chunk of html that was generated from a modal by the user. And this type of interaction has the potential to happen several times. As such I don't think just hiding that html chunk every time would be a good solution.

Comment: @KyleRohlfing, when you are trying to match the last occurrence, do you mean the last set of `<hr/>` and `<div/>` tags to be matched?

Comment: @SunnyPatel Yeah, I want to grab the very last <hr /> tag plus the <div>...</div> block immediately following it in the string.

Comment: Use DOM manipulation routes to find the elements, delete them, replace them, whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regular expressions for this. Assuming you have a container `<div id="stuff"/>` that wraps the code in the OP:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#stuff > hr:nth-last-of-type(1), #stuff > div:nth-last-of-type(1)');
```

If you are using jQuery:

```
$('#stuff > hr:nth-last-of-type(1), #stuff > div:nth-last-of-type(1)');
```

These selectors basically select the last `<hr/>` and `<div/>` tag children within `<div id="stuff"/>` and should be sufficient enough to grab those elements and do as you wish with them.